# Weird redirect issue when using Auth and admin prefix in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication, redirect

I'm using the `admin` prefix in my Cakephp app, for some admin views. I'm also using Auth to restrict access to those views, based on a `role` field in the User table. Pretty standard.

The problem is, that when an unauthorized user tries to go to, say, `admin/users`, (in this case the index action is prohibited), they are redirected to `/admin/users/login` which of course, doesn't exist.

This doesn't happen with actions that do not have the admin prefix. Those behave just fine.

Why are users being sent to to a login that is prepended by the admin prefix and the prohibited action?

Comment: Try setting `'admin'=>false` in your  `loginAction`. Once a [prefix is used](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing), all future URL's use it, until you "come out" of the prefix

Comment: @Ross I think you should make that an answer. I'm pretty sure that's what's happening.

Comment: Ross, make that the answer so I can give credit where credit is due!

Answer (score 7):

Anyone who is still having trouble with this, according to the documentation you can use an array or a string in loginAction ([Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3a%24loginAction)).

Using an array and setting 'admin' => false was still giving me trouble, so I tried using a string instead:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect'  => array('controller' => 'dashboards', 'action' => 'home'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginAction'    => '/users/login',
        'authorize'      => array('Actions')
    ),
);
```

This ended up solving my problem.  Hopefully it works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the specific prefix in the routing array.

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array(
   'controller' => 'users', 
   'action' => 'login', 
   'admin' => false
);
```

or, if you're using multiple prefixes, you can dynamically remove the prefix name like this:

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array(
   'controller' => 'users', 
   'action' => 'login', 
   $this->request->prefix => false
);
```